# Radar chart in R - how to set 50 as the mean and 10 as SD?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I'm quite new to R (and data science in general) and I got stuck with a radar chart recently. I couldn't find the answer online hence I'm asking you for help.

I have a set of multivariate data on a likert scale (values 1-5). I have clustered the data and now I want to visually present the differences between clusters using the radar chart. These differences are not very big, but interesting from the point of view of my project. Inspired by one paper, I want to use their solution and set 50 as the mean and 10 as SD, so that the differences are easily visible.

These are the means of one of the clusters I want to present on a radar chart:

```
cluster1 <- data.frame(3.127168, 3.487457, 3.276144, 3.405147, 3.257353)
colnames(cluster1)=c("F" , "PH" , "PP" , "PN" , "PF")
```

And, just in case, these are the means and SDs from the general sample:

```
general.means <- c(3.658235, 3.220432, 3.393269, 2.793084, 2.688797)
general.sd <- c(0.59, 0.54, 0.56, 0.73, 0.67)
general.sample <- as.data.frame(rbind(general.means, general.sd))
colnames(general.sample)=c("F" , "PH" , "PP" , "PN" , "PF")
```

Now, how do I set 50 as the mean and 10 as SD so that my data looks like in the figure below?
["Profiles are shown using T-scores for each ZTPI subscale, where 50 is the mean and 10 is the standard deviation", (McKay, Cole, & Andretta, 2016)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXYGv.jpg)

Please advice me whether I should scale the data somehow first or do I just set the parameters of a radar chart in specific way? I will be very thankful for your help!

Comment: The image you link to use t scores to standardise, so I would guess you want to convert to t or z scores? How many observations do you have?

Comment: I've got 240 observations, approximately 60 per cluster. I have standardised them  into z scores (subtracted the mean and divided by SD). Is there any way I can set 50 as the mean and 10 as SD during the standardisation process?